# (Newbie) Ending a program, even or odd program

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, scanf, do-while

i'm writing a program to find if a number is even or odd. It will keep asking for a number until the user enters zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int number = 1;

    do{
        printf("Number? ");
        scanf("%d", &number)
    
        if(number % 2 != 0){
            printf("Odd\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("Even\n");
        }
    }while(number != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

I don't however know how to end the program when i type zero without it outputting "even". Help is much appreciated since i am stuck on this and not too sure how to advance.

Comment: Why don't you check that number isn't 0 before printing even?

Comment: You *must* check the value returned by scanf.  Always.  Consider how your program behaves when given "foo" as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `else` to and `else if` and check that the number is not `0` before printing `Even`.

Just add the conditional statement `if(number != 0)` to your `else` block:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int number = 1;

    do{
        printf("Number? ");
        scanf("%d", &number)
    
        if(number % 2 != 0){
            printf("Odd\n");
        }
        else if(number != 0){
            printf("Even\n");
        }
    }while(number != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int number = 1;

    do{
        printf("Number? ");
        scanf("%d", &number)

        if (number == 0)
        {
            printf("You Entered 0 to quit\n");
            break;   // Exit out of the Do-While Loop immediately
        }
    
        if(number % 2 != 0){
            printf("Odd\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("Even\n");
        }
    }while(number != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm being encouraged not to use a 'break' i'm assuming because it's a quicker solution. A valid solution none the less, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is better to use an infinite while loop.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter a number (0 - exit): " );
        
        int number;
        
        if ( scanf( "%d", &number ) != 1 || number == 0 ) break;
        
        printf( "The number %d is %s.\n", number, number % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd" );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a number (0 - exit): 10
The number 10 is even.
Enter a number (0 - exit): 11
The number 11 is odd.
Enter a number (0 - exit): 0
```

You can also include in the program the header `<stdbool.h>`

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

and rewrite the while statement like

```
    while ( true )
    {
        // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the `exit()` function on a return or directly on a `return 0`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int number = 1;

    do{
        printf("Number? ");
        scanf("%d", &number)
        if (number == 0)
          return 0;
    
        if(number % 2 != 0){
            printf("Odd\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("Even\n");
        }
    }while(number != 0);

    return 0;
}
```